# Если обе переменные равны нужно остановить программу и вывести результат

Tags: python

Не работает оператор break, пишет none, а потом краш. Как исправить код, чтобы при получении двух одинаковых значений он останавливался.

```
import random


def lucky():
    x = random.randrange(1, 65)
    y = random.randrange(1, 65)
    print(x, y)
    equal(x, y)


def equal(x, y):
    while x != y:
        print(lucky())
        if x == y:
            break
        print(x, y)


lucky()
```

Comment: 1. Сделай заголовок короче и лаконичнее. Основную часть вопроса перенеси в сам вопрос. 2. Напши более понятно, что ты хочешь сделать, и что не получается. 3. Оператор break работает **100%**. Если у тебя что-то не так, что проблема в твоем коде, а не в операторе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```py
import random

def lucky():
    x = random.randrange(1, 65)
    y = random.randrange(1, 65)
    print(x, y)
    return x, y

def equal():
    while True:
        x, y = lucky()
        if x == y:
            break

equal()
```

Пример вывода:

```
21 10
52 10
30 34
8 23
23 26
7 16
42 14
19 39
48 32
19 53
60 64
44 41
9 49
46 47
43 6
1 60
41 31
31 4
22 60
27 54
52 30
28 50
48 25
43 16
28 20
64 13
15 50
18 16
8 64
19 51
21 2
35 38
34 35
53 62
53 52
10 10
```

Вкратце про ошибки и т.д.:

- не нужно несколько раз печатать одно и то же, печатайте `x` и `y` где-то в одном месте
- для того, чтобы проверять результат работы одной функции в другой функции, нужно возвращать из той результат и присваивать его куда-то
- используйте "бесконечный" цикл `while` с условием и `break` внутри цикла - это удобно
- если функция ничего не возвращает, то на самом деле она возвращает `None`, который вы и печатали
- старайтесь не использовать рекурсию (циклический вызов функции самой из себя сразу или по цепочке управления), тщательно не продумав архитектуру кода, в рекурсии очень легко запутаться и сделать её бесконечной, что у вас и произошло